Origin of Angular Momentum in Accretion disk formation
I read this  paper,  Formation of the Asymmetric Accretion Disk from Stellar Wind Accretion in an S-type Symbiotic Star, I didn't quite understand where the angular momentum came from.
Where I'm getting stuck is you have a ball or cloud of gas sitting there being compressed by gravity, where and when does it start to spin?
Or is it a region in the gas cloud that happens to have a strong vortex already, and that momentum is conserved throughout the star formation process.

An S-type symbiotic system is a white dwarf and mass-losing red giant orbiting each other.
The angular momentum of the accreted material comes from the specific angular momentum the red giant wind has as a result of its binary motion.
The material has too much angular momentum to fall directly onto the white dwarf, so forms an accretion disc, where it gradually loses energy and angular momentum before being accreted.

Note that angular momentum
$$
\vec L = \vec r \times\vec p
$$
is dependent on position. Consider an object moving along a straight line that does not pass through your position. This object will have angular momentum with respect to you. If an object therefore approaches a star without going on a direct collision course, it will have angular momentum with respect to the star, and can enter a stable orbit under the right initial conditions. Of course, a cloud of hot gas will not just start spinning without some prior collapse happening.

paulina, collapse from the gases being compressed fast enough by gravity you mean?  when I look at a gas I see it's rather chaotic system.  unless they act more or less like a fluid when they are collapsing, even then it's kind of hard to see how the spinning can be sustained, since it's cooling down and losing energy.

@sqljunkey that's the whole point. As long as the gas has near-uniform density, all the angular momenta the particles have with respect to each other cancel out. But once the gas cloud has collapsed to form a protostar, there now exists a preferred direction of motion in the cloud (towards the protostar) and we can start to see some spinning happen. But this is not your scenario, as ProfRob points out.
